# How to precompile assets using wildcard on a rails 4.2.6 application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, precompile, bootstrap-sass

I'm currently working on a Rails 4.2.6 application. In the styles sheet folder I have sub directories that represents part of the the application, as shown in the image below: [image]

In the config/initializers/assets.rb file I have the following code:

```
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( faq_page/faq.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( contact/new.css )
```

I have to add each file in order to precompile the assets. I tried using the following code `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']` but it didn't work. I get the following error

> Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

How can I precompile the assets with a wildcard without having to add each `.css` file to assets.rb?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your `/assets` folder should automatically be included in the asset pipeline. You should be able to remove `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']` from your assets initializer altogether.

The only time you should have to add to `config.assets.precompile` is when you want to add assets from a directory such as `/vendor`

Comment: I still the error ```Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( faq_page/faq.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server```

Comment: Any reason they need to be in subdirectories instead of at `/assets`? Also, have you tried renaming them to `.scss`?

Comment: the names of the file are `.css.scss` for example `faq.css.scss` and there shouldn't be issues being subfolders since its in the assets folder thats just a way to keep things organize

Comment: Yeah, just thought it might be worth trying for the purpose of troubleshooting